# Currency field on Field ( redux-form ) for mobile app

Tags: forms, reactjs, cordova, redux, currency

I am currently developing a react mobile app.

The issue is that I want to add '£' currency symbol to a form-redux field with `type=number`.

Code

Form

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from "../../pandle-ui/Card";
import cssmodules from 'react-css-modules'
import styles from './form.cssmodule.scss'
import {Field} from "redux-form";
import CardTitleTextField from "../../form_fields/CardTitleTextField";
import {CardText, Divider, IconButton} from "material-ui";
import CardFieldRow from "../../layout/CardFieldRow";
import {TextFieldBase} from "../../form_fields/TextField";
import CurrencyField from "../../form_fields/CurrencyField";
import {CardActions, FlatButton} from "material-ui";
import DoneIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/done'
import {normalizePercentage} from "../../../util/currency_helpers";

class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {config, cancelButton, submit, wrapperRef} = this.props

    return (
      <div styleName="wrapper" ref={wrapperRef} >
        <Card>
          <DescriptionField />
          <CardText  style={ { paddingTop: 0 } }>
            <QuantityField />
            <UnitsField show={config.showUnits} />
            <PriceField />
            <DiscountField show={config.showDiscount} />
            <Totals showTax={config.showTax} />
          </CardText>
          <Divider />
          <CardActions style={{ textAlign: 'right', padding: '0 8px' }}>
            {cancelButton}
            <DoneButton onClick={() => submit()} />
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Form.displayName = 'PagesLineItemsForm';
Form.propTypes = {};
Form.defaultProps = {};

export default cssmodules(Form, styles)

const DescriptionField = (props) =>
  <Field
    label="Description"
    name="description"
    component={CardTitleTextField}
    {...props}
  />

const QuantityField = (props) => 
  <CardFieldRow label="Quantity">
    <Field name="quantity" type="number" component={TextFieldBase} {...props} />
  </CardFieldRow>

const UnitsField = ({ show, ...props }) => {
  if(show){
    return <CardFieldRow label="Unit Type">
      <Field name="unit" component={TextFieldBase} {...props} />
    </CardFieldRow>
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

const PriceField = (props) =>
  <CardFieldRow label="Price">
    <Field name="price" type="number" component={CurrencyField} {...props} />
  </CardFieldRow>

const DiscountField = ({ show, props }) => {
  if(show){
    return <CardFieldRow label="Discount (%)">
      <Field
        name="discount_percentage"
        component={TextFieldBase}
        type="number"
        normalize={normalizePercentage}
        {...props}
      />
    </CardFieldRow>
  } else {
    return null
  }
}

const Totals = ({ showTax }) => {
  if(showTax){
    return <div>
      <NetAmountField />
      <TaxAmountField />
      <TotalField />
    </div>
  } else {
    return <TotalField name="net_amount" />
  }
}

const NetAmountField = (props) =>
  <CardFieldRow label="Net Amount">
    <Field name="net_amount" component={CurrencyField} {...props} />
  </CardFieldRow>

const TaxAmountField = (props) => {
  return <CardFieldRow label="Tax Amount">
    <Field name="tax_amount" component={CurrencyField} {...props} />
  </CardFieldRow>;
}

const TotalField = (props) =>
  <CardFieldRow label="Total">
    <Field name="total_amount" disabled={true} component={CurrencyField} {...props} />
  </CardFieldRow>

const DoneButton = (props) => <IconButton {...props}><DoneIcon /></IconButton>
```

CurrencyField.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {TextFieldBase} from "./TextField";
import {formatCurrency} from "../../util/formatters";
import {truncateCurrency} from "../../util/currency_helpers";
import {createComponentLogger} from "../../util/logging";

export default class CurrencyField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    log('Constructor called with props', props)
    this.state = { value: props.value, focused : false }
    this.baseInputPassProps = this.getBaseInputPassProps()
  }

  getBaseInputPassProps(){
    return {
      onChange: (e) => this.onChange(truncateCurrency(e.target.value)),
      onBlur: (e) => this.onBlur(truncateCurrency(e.target.value)),
      onFocus: (e) => this.onFocus()
    }
  }

  onChange(value){
    log('onChange called with', value)
    safeParse(value, parsed => {
      if(log('should update state', this.shouldUpdateStateValue(value))){
        this.setState({ value })
        this.props.input.onChange(parsed*100)
      }
    })
  }

  onBlur(value){
    log('onBlur called with', value)
    safeParse(value, parsed => {
      this.props.input.onBlur(parsed*100)
    })
  }

  onFocus(){
    log('onFocus called')
    this.props.input.onFocus()
  }

  shouldUpdateStateValue(value){
    return this.state.value !== value
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const {value} = nextProps.input
    log('will receive props', nextProps)

    if(log('should update props value', this.shouldUpdatePropsValue(value))){
      this.setState({
        value: log('updating state.value', (value/100).toString())
      })
    }
  }

  shouldUpdatePropsValue(value){
    const {input, meta: {active}} = this.props
    return !active && input.value !== value
  }

  render(){
    log('Render called')
    return <TextFieldBase
      {...log('Props for TextField', this.getTextFieldProps())}
    />
  }

  getTextFieldProps(){
    const {value, ...props} = this.props
    return Object.assign({}, props, this.getPassProps())
  }

  getPassProps(){
    return { input: log('Input pass props', this.getInputPassProps()) }
  }

  getInputPassProps(){
    return Object.assign({}, this.props.input, this.baseInputPassProps, {
      value: log('Value for input pass props', this.getValue())
    })
  }

  getValue(){
    if(this.props.meta.active){
      return log('active, state', this.state.value)
    } else if(this.props.input.value) {
      return log('inactive, formatted', this.getFormattedValue())
    } else {
      return ''
    }
  }

  getFormattedValue() {
    return (this.props.input.name === 'price') ?
      this.props.input.value / 100
      :
      formatCurrency(
        null,
        log('for currency formatter', this.props.input.value / 100)
      )
  }
}

function safeParse(value, fn){
  const parsed = Number(value)
  log(`parsed ${value} as `, parsed)
  !isNaN(parsed) && fn(parsed)
}

CurrencyField.displayName = 'CurrencyField'

const log = createComponentLogger(CurrencyField.displayName)
```

formatters.js

```
import numeral from 'numeral'
import 'numeral/locales/en-gb'
import moment from 'moment'

numeral.locale('en-gb');

export function formatCurrencyPence(number){
  return (number > 0) ? formatCurrency(null, number/100) : '-'
}

export function formatCurrency(symbol='£', number){
  return numeral(number).format('($0,0.00)')
}


export function formatAmount(number){
  return numeral(number).format('-0,0.00')
}

export function formatInvoiceProps(item){
  return [
    formatInvoiceDates,
    formatInvoiceAmounts
  ].reduce((memo, fn) => fn(memo), item)
}


const formatInvoiceDates = createFormatter(
  formatServerDate,
  'date',
  'date-due'
)

function formatServerDate(date){
  return formatMomentDate(serverToMomentDate(date))
}

function serverToMomentDate(date){
  return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
}

/**
 * @param date {moment}
 */
export function formatMomentDate(date){
  return (date.isValid() && date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')) || '-'
}

export function formatDate(date){
  return formatMomentDate(moment(date))
}

const formatInvoiceAmounts = createFormatter(
  formatInvoiceAmount,
  'net-amount',
  'tax-amount',
  'total-amount'
)

function formatInvoiceAmount(amount){
  return formatCurrency(null, amount)
}

function createFormatter(formatter, ...keys){
  return ob => formatProps(ob, formatter, keys)
}

function formatProps(ob, formatter, keys){
  return keys.reduce(formatProp(formatter), ob)
}

function formatProp(formatter){
  return (ob, k) => {
    const v = ob[k]
    return v ? Object.assign({}, ob, { [k] : formatter(v, ob) }) : ob
  }
}
```

This code uses number pad when the user tap in the field which is fine, but how can I format that?

Also, how can I prevent users to insert negative numbers?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you include the code code for `normalizePercentage`. I though normalize would be the place to make such additions to the input going in  It would also help if you got a working demo running for JSFiddle or something like that. I know some Redux form stuff, but not enough to solve this without have any code to do trial-and-error with.

Comment: Sure, I edited my question above.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm beginning to see that this is probably over my head. I know too little about Redux Form. But like I hinted before I think `normalize` is the key to both your problems. The documentation has an example where they add dashes to a telephone number (similar to adding £, I guess). and they have an example where they restrict the range of a number (similar to not allowing negative numbers). But maybe you'll have to change the number field to text (like they have with the phone number) to allow £. http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/normalizing/

Comment: The problem is if I change the `input=text` the number pad will not come up in the devices. Thank you for your help. I will check the normalizing example they have there. Cheers

Comment: Oh, you mean THAT kind of numpad. Yeah, I've run into a similar problem before (not with Redux Form). I think we had to do a custom solution. I've heard some people try to use the `type=tel`  for similar issues.. but haven't tried it. Good luck!

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question. I want to get $x,xxx.xx format